# returning null array in getting photos albums

Tags: php, facebook

```
<?php
$user_id = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'email,photo_upload');
$has_permission = $facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission("photo_upload");
$albums=$facebook->api_client->photos_getAlbums($user_id, NULL);
var_dump($albums);
?>
```

I am getting null when run this code

Comment: Are you sure `$facebook` and `$user_id` are correctly set?
Try `var_dump($facebook)` for instance.

I don't use Facebook so can't really test that, but from their documentation it seems there's a third parameter to pass (?)  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.getAlbums

Comment: well i am using old facebook api 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Photos.getAlbums
so according to this tuts i did this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific?

try to pass varialbe as a second argument